# How to Tell Difference Between status="closed" and {if no_results}?

Tags: channel-entries, safecracker, channel-form, status

I have a safecracker form I just converted to channel:form and I just changed it so when an entry is created it's automatically set to status="closed"

What I'm trying to do is display a message if the created entry is still being moderated (status is closed), display a message if there is NO entry created, or display a msg if there IS an entry created.. How do I tell the difference?

```
{exp:channel:entries
channel="personal_trainer_directory"
limit="1"
dynamic="no"
author_id="CURRENT_USER"
status="closed"
}
    ***DISPLAY IF STATUS IS CLOSED***
{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:channel:entries
channel="personal_trainer_directory"
limit="1"
dynamic="no"
author_id="CURRENT_USER"
}
    {if  no_results}
    ***DISPLAY IF NO RESULTS***
    {/if}
    ***DISPLAY IF THERE IS A RESULT***
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    {exp:channel:entries
channel="personal_trainer_directory"
limit="1"
dynamic="no"
author_id="CURRENT_USER"
status="open|closed"
}
    {if  no_results}
    ***DISPLAY IF NO RESULTS***
    {/if}

{if status=="closed"}
    ***DISPLAY IF STATUS IS CLOSED***
{if:else}
    ***DISPLAY IF THERE IS A RESULT***

{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Is that what you mean?